# Grok pattern working fine on Kibana Grok Debbuger but not with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I want to create default Filebeat[System] dashboards that include dashboard for **sudo-commands**, **ssh logins**, and **syslogs**.

**My Logstash filter block looks like this:**

```
filter {
   if [fileset][module] == "system" {
        if [fileset][name] == "auth" {
          grok {
            match => { "message" => ["%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} sshd(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: %{DATA:[system][auth][ssh][event]} %{DATA:[system][auth][ssh][method]} for (invalid user )?%{DATA:[system][auth][user]} from %{IPORHOST:[system][auth][ssh][ip]} port %{NUMBER:[system][auth][ssh][port]} ssh2(: %{GREEDYDATA:[system][auth][ssh][signature]})?",
                      "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} sshd(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: %{DATA:[system][auth][ssh][event]} user %{DATA:[system][auth][user]} from %{IPORHOST:[system][auth][ssh][ip]}",
                      "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} sshd(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: Did not receive identification string from %{IPORHOST:[system][auth][ssh][dropped_ip]}",
                      "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} sudo(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: \s*%{DATA:[system][auth][user]} :( %{DATA:[system][auth][sudo][error]} ;)? TTY=%{DATA:[system][auth][sudo][tty]} ; PWD=%{DATA:[system][auth][sudo][pwd]} ; USER=%{DATA:[system][auth][sudo][user]} ; COMMAND=%{GREEDYDATA:[system][auth][sudo][command]}",
                      "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} groupadd(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: new group: name=%{DATA:system.auth.groupadd.name}, GID=%{NUMBER:system.auth.groupadd.gid}",
                      "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} useradd(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: new user: name=%{DATA:[system][auth][user][add][name]}, UID=%{NUMBER:[system][auth][user][add][uid]}, GID=%{NUMBER:[system][auth][user][add][gid]}, home=%{DATA:[system][auth][user][add][home]}, shell=%{DATA:[system][auth][user][add][shell]}$",
                      "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} %{DATA:[system][auth][program]}(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: %{GREEDYMULTILINE:[system][auth][message]}"] }
            pattern_definitions => {
              "GREEDYMULTILINE"=> "(.|\n)*"
            }
            remove_field => "message"
          }
          date {
            match => [ "[system][auth][timestamp]", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
          }
          geoip {
            source => "[system][auth][ssh][ip]"
            target => "[system][auth][ssh][geoip]"
          }
        }
        else if [fileset][name] == "syslog" {
          grok {
            match => { "message" => ["%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][syslog][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][syslog][hostname]} %{DATA:[system][syslog][program]}(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][syslog][pid]}\])?: %{GREEDYMULTILINE:[system][syslog][message]}"] }
            pattern_definitions => { "GREEDYMULTILINE" => "(.|\n)*" }
            remove_field => "message"
          }
          date {
            match => [ "[system][syslog][timestamp]", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Log Message:**

```
Oct 23 13:18:56 compnode33 sudo: dummyuser : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/dummyuser ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/cat /etc/hosts
```

To build the dashboard few metdata are required. The grok pattern for sudo command in Kibana Grok debugger works fine but in realtime, with the same pattern Logstash not able to generate the following metadata.

```
{
  "[system][auth][sudo][tty]": "pts/0",
  "[system][auth][sudo][pwd]": "/home/dummyuser",
  "[system][auth][sudo][user]": "root",
  "[system][auth][user]": "dummyuser",
  "[system][auth][sudo][command]": "/bin/cat /etc/hosts",
  "[system][auth][timestamp]": "Oct 23 13:18:56",
  "[system][auth][hostname]": "compnode33"
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Can you tell us what error message or tag you get?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you can also split your grok filter in multiple filters, with conditionals so that the right message format goes to the right filter. And perhaps for key-value data, it might work better with the kv filter.

Answer (score 0):

Without an actual error message or tags, it's hard to tell what's going on...
However, with that many patterns listed in your `grok` filter, I suspect you are getting a grok timeout.

In that case, the solution is to use anchors (`^` and `$`) to make each pattern bail out faster:

```
grok {
  match => {
    "message" => [
      "^%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} sshd(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: %{DATA:[system][auth][ssh][event]} %{DATA:[system][auth][ssh][method]} for (invalid user )?%{DATA:[system][auth][user]} from %{IPORHOST:[system][auth][ssh][ip]} port %{NUMBER:[system][auth][ssh][port]} ssh2(: %{GREEDYDATA:[system][auth][ssh][signature]})?$",
      "^%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} sshd(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: %{DATA:[system][auth][ssh][event]} user %{DATA:[system][auth][user]} from %{IPORHOST:[system][auth][ssh][ip]}$",
      "^%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} sshd(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: Did not receive identification string from %{IPORHOST:[system][auth][ssh][dropped_ip]}$",
      "^%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} sudo(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: \s*%{DATA:[system][auth][user]} :( %{DATA:[system][auth][sudo][error]} ;)? TTY=%{DATA:[system][auth][sudo][tty]} ; PWD=%{DATA:[system][auth][sudo][pwd]} ; USER=%{DATA:[system][auth][sudo][user]} ; COMMAND=%{GREEDYDATA:[system][auth][sudo][command]}$",
      "^%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} groupadd(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: new group: name=%{DATA:system.auth.groupadd.name}, GID=%{NUMBER:system.auth.groupadd.gid}$",
      "^%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} useradd(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: new user: name=%{DATA:[system][auth][user][add][name]}, UID=%{NUMBER:[system][auth][user][add][uid]}, GID=%{NUMBER:[system][auth][user][add][gid]}, home=%{DATA:[system][auth][user][add][home]}, shell=%{DATA:[system][auth][user][add][shell]}$",
      "^%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][auth][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][auth][hostname]} %{DATA:[system][auth][program]}(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][auth][pid]}\])?: %{GREEDYMULTILINE:[system][auth][message]}$"
    ]
  }
  pattern_definitions => {
    "GREEDYMULTILINE"=> "(.|\n)*"
  }
  remove_field => "message"
}
```

If that still doesn't work, try using more specific patterns instead of `DATA`, `GREEDYDATA` and `GREEDYMULTILINE`.

References:

- [Do you grok Grok?](https://www.elastic.co/blog/do-you-grok-grok)
- [Killing your Logstash performance with Grok](https://medium.com/@momchil.dev/killing-your-logstash-performance-with-grok-f5f23ae47956)

Comment: I tried using anchor but the result is the same, no results for dashboards. Also, I checked the logs but I was not able to find any significant errors.